# How do I exit full screen in VMWare Fusion 7?

Tags: vmware

How do I exit full screen in VMWare Fusion 7?

The menu bar that used to appear when the cursor was oushed to the top of the screen no longer appears.

Comment: and the Exit Full Screen view.
■
 

In the Full Screen title bar, select View > Single Window or View > Unity.
■
 

Use the keyboard shortcut Command key+Control+Return to exit Full Screen to Single Window view.
■
 

Use the keyboard shortcut Command key+Control+U to exit to Unity view. is not working ?

Comment: There is no "Full Screen title bar."

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To enter or exit Fullscreenmode of your VM you can press [Command]+[Control]+[F].

Comment: Thank you - just an FYI This command has to be done on the Windows side. I just fought with it for 30 minutes. UGH!!!

Comment: Still works with Fusion 11.